# Media query in mixin being overridden

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, google-chrome-devtools

I made a 'responsive property' mixin which takes a css property and its values at five different breakpoints as arguments:

```
@mixin responsiveProp ($prop, $xs, $sm, $md, $lg, $xlg) {
  @media only screen and (min-width: 0px) {
    #{$prop}: $xs;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #{$prop}: $sm;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    #{$prop}: $md;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    #{$prop}: $lg;
  }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    #{$prop}: $xlg;
  }
}
```

e.g. `@include responsiveProp(height, 1300px, 900px, 550px, 500px, 500px);`

This generally works great as a way to reduce LOC in CSS, however when testing the above example with a smartphone layout in Chrome Dev Tools, the $xs breakpoint is overridden by the $sm breakpoint despite the width being < 768px. I can't understand why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: You should combine min and max: `...and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width:767px)` (max should be the next min -1 )

Comment: @somethinghere nope it still doesn't work, it shouldn't make any difference anyway should it as the logic for the conditions being met hasn't changed

Comment: Whats your output? And do you have the correct viewport meta tag set?

Comment: Ah yes, I had missed the viewport tag. Thanks!

Comment: That isn't really useful in this format. Could you isolate the output and add it to your post? There must be something else doing something here. (Just a sidenote, but this system will create _a lot of rules with @media_ if you are not careful, so keep that in mind)

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to add this to my index.html: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`. That solved the problem.

Comment: Woopwoop. Good stuff, although you should immediatly notice this on device :)